# D3 - Nesting multiple charts from the same dataset

Tags: d3.js

I have the following code;

```
var matrix = [
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4],
  [ 5, 6, 7, 8]
];

var tr = d3.selectAll("td.sparkline").append("table").selectAll("tr")
.data(matrix)
.enter()
.append("tr");

var td = tr.selectAll("td")
.data(function(d) { return d; })
.enter()
.append("td")
.text(function(d) { return d; });
```

What is the correct way to do the following;

```
<td class="sparkline">matrix[0]</td>
<td class="sparkline">matrix[1]</td>
```

Can I use the same class for the container? 
I keep getting both arrays in both rows.

I read about the nesting here 
http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/ 
but I still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish here. Do you have a table with a `td` element with class `"sparkline"` already in the DOM, and you're trying to add a new table inside it? Or do you want a new table somewhere else? Do you want one cell per number in your matrix, or one cell per row in the matrix?

This fiddle illustrates the above choices: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/ma7Dn/

In the first version, the code is as you've provided it, and there's an existing table in the DOM with a `td.sparkline` element to append new content to. The result is a new table within that `td`, with rows and cells corresponding to your matrix structure.

In the second version, we're appending a new table to a different element, with one row per row in the matrix and one cell per row:

```
  var tr2 = d3.select("#v2").append("table").selectAll("tr")
    .data(matrix)
  .enter().append("tr").append("td")
    .attr("class", "sparkline")
    .text(function(d) { return d.join(", "); });
```

The first version works as expected with your own code, so I'm assuming that's not what you want. My guess is that your initial selector `td.sparkline` is the cause of the confusion; if that's not referencing something already in the DOM, it's an error here.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Let me clarify, because i got the table example from here > http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/ I have a table that I generate with php, now I want a sparkline in each row (or better in each <td class="sparkline"></td>) through d3. Since I have multiple sparkline classes, I can use select("td.sparkline") which give me all the sparklines in the first row or td.selectAll which gives me all the sparklines in all the rows. Is there a way to give me the correct sparkline in the correct row.

Comment: Where I said td.selectAll I meant selectAll("td.sparkline")

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...

```
d3.selectAll('td.sparkline')
.data(matrix)
.text(function(d, i)
   { return 'Result #' + (i + 1) + ': ' + d; // i is 0-based.
});
```

gives me the ability to add each index to the correct row.
This link was pretty helpful;
http://code.hazzens.com/d3tut/lesson_1.html